# Laravel Passport -> micro service user authentication

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

For an application I've made a bunch of MicroServices and a Gateway. The gateway receives the request and collects the data from the giroservices. All working fine.

The gateway accepts all the requests and authenticates them using Laravel Passport. So the gateway has Laravel Passport installed.

```
[gateway]/users/login accepts the login parameters: 
[users]/users/verify login details and returns user object. All works fine.
```

UserController.php

```
public function login(Request $request){

        $rules = [
            'email'     => 'required|email:rfc',
            'password'  => 'required|min:8',
        ];

        $user = $this->userService->verifyUser(['email'=> $request->email, 'password'=> $request->password]);


        return $this->successResponse(['token'=>$token], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

The `$user` has the full User json including the UUID. I want to attach that UUID Laravel Passports OAuth. So that when the user authenticates, I can abstract the User UUID and use that for next requests.

`{"data":{"uuid":"94b55bed-f084-468a-a2a7-51d38e96aed3","first_name":"John","last_name":"Due","locale":"en","email":"JohnDoe@mail.com","created_at":"2020-12-10T09:40:46.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-10T09:40:46.000000Z"}}`

Obviously I understand to json_decode this, but how to manually create an access token in Laravel Passport. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an access token using a password grant client_id and client_secret along with the user credentials. You can do this using the /oauth/token route in the service that is holding the passport logic.

Here from the documentation

```
Creating A Password Grant Client
Before your application can issue tokens via the password grant, you will need to create a password grant client. You may do this using the passport:client Artisan command with the --password option. If you have already run the passport:install command, you do not need to run this command:

php artisan passport:client --password
Requesting Tokens
Once you have created a password grant client, you may request an access token by issuing a POST request to the /oauth/token route with the user's email address and password. Remember, this route is already registered by the Passport::routes method so there is no need to define it manually. If the request is successful, you will receive an access_token and refresh_token in the JSON response from the server:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://passport-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
    'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
    'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
    'password' => 'my-password',
    'scope' => '',
]);

return $response->json();
```

which can be found here.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client